# C# server not receiving sockets on some pc's

Tags: c#, android, sockets, packets

Okay guys I have a really weird issue.
I've created an Android application who should send a token to a C# server.

This is the android client code implementation. So nothing weird, this should work.
What it should do is to send a token to the server. The server has a listener who listens on the same port(4444)

```
        Socket s = new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, 4444);
        output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream())),false);
        output.println(token);
        output.flush();

        output.close();
        s.close();
```

This is the server C# implementation:

```
 CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        String hostname = "";
        System.Net.IPHostEntry ip = new IPHostEntry();
        hostname = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
        ip = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);

        foreach (System.Net.IPAddress listip in ip.AddressList)
        {
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse(listip.ToString());
            int port = 4444;
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAd, port);
            if (listip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                writeConsole("Server ip: " + listip);

            }
            writeConsole("Server listening to port: " + port);
            tcpListener.Start();
        }

        // Start listening for incoming data
        new Thread(connect).Start();
```

connect method:

```
while (true)
        {
            serversocket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
            byte[] data_rec = new byte[1024];
            int k = serversocket.Receive(data_rec);
            writeConsole("Receiving client data");

            char cc;
            String mes = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++)
            {
                cc = Convert.ToChar(data_rec[i]);
                mes += cc.ToString();
            }
            if (mes != null)
            {
                writeConsole("Client connected - token: " + mes);
                registrationIDList.Add(mes);

            }
        }
```

This code should catch the incoming socket and add the received token to a List.

Well this should work, or probably shouldn't. Otherwise I wasn't posting this question.
The strange part though is that it works on my personal laptop, and some other pc's but it doesn't work on the desktop pc of my client where I make this application for.

When I execute the server application on my clients pc it doesn't receive any data sent by the client.
Now I've tried a lot, so I think i've tried all the most common solutions you could think of but without result.

Let me show what I already tried:
After the first few attempts we decided to do a clean install on the desktop so there wouldn't be any software/settings that could be the problem, so I tried all these solutions on a clean installed Windows 10 X64 system(my system is a Windows 10 X64 as well)

- Disabled firewall
- Explicitly allowed the application in the firewall.
- Opened port 4444 in the advanced firewall settings
- Tried other ports
- Checked if the packets were received by the system(using netstat). Result: 192.168.1.22:4444 androidxxxxxx CLOSE_WAIT
- probably more stuff

So what I could conclude out of this was that the packages are received (because netstat sees em), but somewhere on the way to the application they get lost, or get blocked which seems strange because it couldn't the firewall should allow them.

Another thing i think the problem could be in is the classes i use.

I use an TCPListener which is a high level class. I thought of writing my own TCPListener but then i thought why would it work on my systems and not on my client's. That was the point that i needed you guys because i'm really stuck. 
Especially because it works on some systems but doesn't on others.

Comment: Is the c# app binding (LocalEndpoint) to the correct adapter/interface? IIRC leaving the default can bind to an ipv6 interface

Comment: Could you post the listener initialization?

Comment: How much data is the client sending? If the data is larger than your buffer size of 1024 bytes, then your server code would not receive the entire message. You would need to create a loop around the call to `Receive()` [like this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Use HWGroup Hercules as TCP Server instead for testing. Use Sysinternals TCPView for monitoring the connections. This may help you find the failure. If needed, also use wireshark to monitor the traffic. The 3 mentioned programs are basic tools for c# network diagnosis. Furthermore, you could enable logging in the Windows firewall.

Comment: How far did you debug and step over the code? Do you get the console prints as expected? Does the program maybe not even enter the loop in the misbehaving PC? Add another message before waiting for incoming connections.

Comment: @AlexK. I'm not sure.. how could I check that? Or should I just disable the ipv6 adapter?

Comment: @Chase The client is sending 89bytes. And it's probably not a failure in the software because it works on other systems. Yet software has it's strange ways to go.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss I debugged the software and the breakpoint went until serversocket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket()

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem description. _"it doesn't receive the sockets"_ -- what does that mean? The socket is the local abstraction that represents a network endpoint; you don't receive a socket, the socket itself receives data. Are you not receiving data? Or are you having trouble with getting the socket connected at all? In either case, without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to know for sure what might be wrong.

Comment: You should keep in mind that in TCP **there is no such thing as a "packet"**. And I would say your means of receiving data is about as inelegant as it gets. And it's not clear why you ignore the last byte that was received. But other than that, I'm not seeing anything obviously _wrong_ per se.